# Theano stack matrices programmatically?

Tags: python, theano

I have the following code which stacks 2 matrices into a 3D tensor.

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
A = T.matrix("A")
B = theano.tensor.stack(A, A)
f = theano.function(inputs=[A], outputs=B)
print f([range(10)]*2)
```

However, I do not know how many times I need to stack the matrix in advance. For example the fourth line of code may be:

```
B = theano.tensor.stack(A, A, A)
B = theano.tensor.stack(A, A, A, A)
etc...
```

Is there a theano function to duplicate a matrix n times:

```
theano.some_function(A, 3) = theano.tensor.stack(A, A, A)
```

Then I can pass that 3, as an argument to the theano function f. Is this possible? I looked into broadcasting but broadcasting does not explicitly change dimensionality/stack.

Comment: Are you sure you need this? What problem are you trying to solve? Mostly, when matrix replication comes up, the problem can be formulated differently, avoiding it. I will post an answer using broadcasting, just to complete the picture, but the actual change you want to make is problem-dependent.

Answer (score 2):

After digging long and hard through the theano documentation I have found the solution:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
A = T.matrix("A")
B = [A]
C = theano.tensor.extra_ops.repeat(B, 3, axis=0)
f = theano.function(inputs=[A], outputs=C)
print f([range(10)]*2)
```

is equivalent to:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
A = T.matrix("A")
B = theano.tensor.stack(A, A, A)
f = theano.function(inputs=[A], outputs=B)
print f([range(10)]*2)
```

except we can now choose the number of repeats programatically as the second argument to: theano.tensor.extra_ops.repeat

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using broadcasting

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy as np

A = T.fmatrix()
n = T.iscalar()

ones = T.ones((n, 1, 1))

stackedA = ones * A[np.newaxis, :, :]

f = theano.function([A, n], stackedA)

a = np.arange(30).reshape(5, 6).astype('float32')
nn = 3

r = f(a, nn)

print r.shape  # outputs (3, 4, 5)
print (r == a[np.newaxis]).all()  # outputs True
```

This approach can help the compiler avoid tiling if it can optimize that away.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about theano, but you could accomplish this using list comprehension and unpacking argument list:

```
n = 5
B = theano.tensor.stack(*[A for dummy in range(n)])
```

which is equivalent to:

```
B = theano.tensor.stack(A, A, A, A, A)
```

What this does is, it first constructs a list with `n` copies of `A` and then unpacks this list into separate arguments (see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: Thanks, that works for general functions but theano is a bit different: f = theano.function(inputs=[A], outputs=B) creates a theano function, and the ideal syntax would be something like this: f = theano.function(inputs=[A, 5], outputs=B)

Comment: @applecider I tried this and it worked also in your example. But since you already got another solution, it doesn't really matter.